# Limit of a rational function tending to infinity

Tags: limits, functions, reference-request

While i was searching for the limit at infinity of a rational function, I found [this link of math libretext.](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Monroe_Community_College/MTH_210_Calculus_I/Chapter_2_Limits/2.5%3A_Limits_at_Infinity#:%7E:text=To%20evaluate%20the%20limits%20at,at%20large%20values%20of%20x.)

And as I scrolled down, I found this equation

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x→±∞}\frac{3x^2+2x}{4x^3−5x+7}=\displaystyle \lim_{x→±∞}\frac{3/x+2/x^2}{4−5/x^2+7/x^3}=\frac{3.0+2.0}{4−5.0+7.0}=0.$$

I don't understand how the author got from $2nd$ equation to $3rd$ and from $3rd$ to $4th$. Am I missing out on something?

My understanding is in the 2nd equation, we will invoke the reciprocal function to help us out. and Limit tend to infinity, the reciprocal tends to $0$. So we will have

$$\displaystyle \displaystyle \lim_{x→±∞}\frac{3/x+2/x^2}{4−5/x^2+7/x^3}=\frac{0+0}{4−0+0}=\frac{0}{4}=0.$$

Which is the same answer but in different method. Have I got anything wrong?

(Note: question is example 2.2.5, question b. I haven't read all of it, only the section I googled for, so that might explain if I got something wrong)

Comment: You did exactly the same thing: what you’re reading as decimal points are actually intended to be multiplication signs, e.g., $3\cdot 0+2\cdot 0$ in the numerator.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh thanks that explains, i spent nearly half an hour thinking about this

Comment: You’re welcome!